# How much specific RID should I use for Azure App Service app?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-appservice

I have an Azure App Service where .NET Core 5.0 app is hosted.

Previously all projects had runtime win-x64, same RID was used in restore-build-publish commands.

I added new NuGet dependency which cannot be restored using this RID so I changed it to win10-x64.

How can this affect my app? Can this change break something?